# Azure pipeline expression does not work in template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have some templates and i'd like to check if variables are set or not.
So i tried this:

Template that gets included:

```yaml
 - ${{if not(variables.assemblyVersion)}}:
   - task: PowerShell@2
     inputs:
       targetType: 'inline'
       script: |
         Write-Host $(assemblyVersion)
         throw "assemblyVersion was not set"
```

But even if set assemblyVersion to something (e.g. `1.2.3.4`) that task is being ran.
What am i doing wrong?

Edit: tried the answer from Krzysztof Madej, and i got false-positives:

Output:

```
2020-11-19T09:36:30.7383677Z ##[section]Starting: PowerShell
2020-11-19T09:36:30.7500976Z ==============================================================================
2020-11-19T09:36:30.7501272Z Task         : PowerShell
2020-11-19T09:36:30.7501523Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
2020-11-19T09:36:30.7501778Z Version      : 2.170.1
2020-11-19T09:36:30.7501984Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-11-19T09:36:30.7502296Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
2020-11-19T09:36:30.7502761Z ==============================================================================
2020-11-19T09:36:31.9944831Z Generating script.
2020-11-19T09:36:32.1228113Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2020-11-19T09:36:32.1504771Z ##[command]"C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\2af656c2-be5b-4a73-8812-17185fff83cc.ps1'"
2020-11-19T09:36:32.4080866Z 1.2.3.4
2020-11-19T09:36:32.7066175Z assemblyVersion was not set
2020-11-19T09:36:32.7066649Z At D:\a\_temp\2af656c2-be5b-4a73-8812-17185fff83cc.ps1:4 char:1
2020-11-19T09:36:32.7067329Z + throw "assemblyVersion was not set"
2020-11-19T09:36:32.7068304Z + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-11-19T09:36:32.7069103Z     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (assemblyVersion was not set:String) [], RuntimeException
2020-11-19T09:36:32.7069840Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : assemblyVersion was not set
2020-11-19T09:36:32.7070536Z  
2020-11-19T09:36:32.8288504Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2020-11-19T09:36:32.8929792Z ##[section]Finishing: PowerShell
```

Main pipeline where yaml is set:

```yaml
trigger:
- master
- feature/*

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
- group: HmiSulis
- name: solution
  value:  AllProjects.sln
- name: buildPlatform
  value: x86
- name: buildConfiguration
  value:  Debug
- name: assemblyVersion
  value: 1.2.3.4
- name: fileVersion
  value: 5.6.7.8
- name: informationalVersion
  value: 9.10.11.12

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: BuildTemplates
      type: git
      name: HMI/BuildTemplates

extends:
  template: netFx/Jobs/netFx.Build.yml@BuildTemplates
```

The job used:

```yaml
jobs:
- job: Build
  steps:
  - template: ../../NuGet/Steps/NuGet.Restore.yml
  - template: ../Steps/netFx.Build.Version.yml
  - template: ../Steps/netFx.Build.yml
```

The steps with the checks (netFx.Build.Version.yml):

```yaml
steps:
- ${{if not(variables['assemblyVersion'])}}:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        Write-Host $(assemblyVersion)
        throw "assemblyVersion was not set"
- ${{if not(variables['fileVersion'])}}:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        throw "fileVersion was not set"
- ${{if not(variables['informationalVersion'])}}:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        throw "informationalVersion was not set"                
- task: Assembly-Info-NetFramework@2
  inputs:
    Path: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    FileNames: |
      **\AssemblyInfo.cs
      **\AssemblyInfo.vb
    InsertAttributes: true
    FileEncoding: 'auto'
    WriteBOM: false
    VersionNumber: '$(assemblyVersion)'
    # File version in windows explorer
    FileVersionNumber: '$(fileVersion)'
    # Product version in windows explorer
    InformationalVersion: '$(informationalVersion)'
    LogLevel: 'verbose'
    FailOnWarning: false
    DisableTelemetry: false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use correct syntax as it is shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditionally-assign-a-variable):

```yaml
variables:
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}: # only works if you have a master branch
    stageName: prod

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- script: echo ${{variables.stageName}}
```

so in your case it would be

```yaml
 - ${{if not(variables['assemblyVersion'])}}:
   - task: PowerShell@2
     inputs:
       targetType: 'inline'
       script: |
         Write-Host $(assemblyVersion)
         throw "assemblyVersion was not set"
```

> You can use an if clause to conditionally assign the value or a variable or set inputs for tasks. Conditionals only work when using template syntax.

I simplified your case and it works:

```yaml
variables:
- name: solution
  value:  AllProjects.sln
- name: buildPlatform
  value: x86
- name: buildConfiguration
  value:  Debug
- name: assemblyVersion
  value: ''
#  value: 1.2.3.4
- name: fileVersion
  value: 5.6.7.8
- name: informationalVersion
  value: 9.10.11.12

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

jobs:
- job: Build
  variables: 
  - name: test
    value: $[not(variables['assemblyVersion'])]
  steps:
  - ${{if not(variables['assemblyVersion'])}}:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      continueOnError: true
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host $(assemblyVersion)
          throw "assemblyVersion was not set"
  - task: PowerShell@2
    continueOnError: true
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        Write-Host $(assemblyVersion)
        Write-Host $(test)
```

So when `assemblyVersion` is given task is skipped. And when is not given task is ran and fail. Be aware `$(assemblyVersion)` it means that variable have to be available even if not set.

I made further tests moving logic to template. So this is my template:

```yaml
jobs:
- job: BuildFromTemplate
  dependsOn: []
  variables: 
  - name: test
    value: $[not(variables['assemblyVersion'])]
  steps:
  - ${{if not(variables['assemblyVersion'])}}:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      continueOnError: true
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host $(assemblyVersion)
          throw "assemblyVersion was not set"
  - task: PowerShell@2
    continueOnError: true
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        Write-Host $(assemblyVersion)
        Write-Host $(test)
```

and here is the pipeline:

```yaml
variables:
- name: assemblyVersion
#  value: ''
  value: 1.2.3.4


pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    variables: 
    - name: test
      value: $[not(variables['assemblyVersion'])]
    steps:
    - ${{if not(variables['assemblyVersion'])}}:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        continueOnError: true
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            Write-Host $(assemblyVersion)
            throw "assemblyVersion was not set"
    - task: PowerShell@2
      continueOnError: true
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host $(assemblyVersion)
          Write-Host $(test)
  - template: template.yaml
```

and yes job in template failed:

[image]

What seems strange, [because](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops):

> The difference between runtime and compile time expression syntaxes is primarily what context is available. In a compile-time expression (${{  }}), you have access to parameters and statically defined variables. In a runtime expression ($[  ]), you have access to more variables but no parameters.

and `assemblyVersion` is statically defined variable.

It looks that we can use only paramaters in template expression in templates and not variables.

I created a [bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1266925/variables-defined-on-pipeline-level-are-not-availa.html) on developer community for this.

IMHO if you want to use template you need to move this condition into task and just skip logic.

```yaml
  - task: PowerShell@2
    continueOnError: true
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $ver = '$(assemblyVersion)'
        Write-Host "Ver: $($ver)"
        if (!$ver)
        {
          throw "assemblyVersion was not set"
        }
```

Or use templates variable and reuse it in main file and template file:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: 'variabaleTemplate'
  default: 'variables.yaml'
  type: string

jobs:
- job: BuildFromTemplate
  dependsOn: []
  variables:
  - template: ${{parameters.variabaleTemplate}}
  - name: test
    value: $[not(variables['assemblyVersion'])]
  steps:
  - ${{if not(variables['assemblyVersion'])}}:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      continueOnError: true
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host $(assemblyVersion)
          throw "assemblyVersion was not set"
```

with `variables.yaml` like

```yaml
variables:
- name: assemblyVersion
#  value: ''
  value: 1.2.3.4
```

and main file like:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: A
  variables:
  - template: variables.yaml
  jobs:
  - template: template2.yaml
```

So I got reply [from MS](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1266925/variables-defined-on-pipeline-level-are-not-availa.html)

> For security reasons, we only allow you to pass information into templated code via explicit parameters.
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops
>
> The means the author of the pipeline using your template needs to commit changes where they explicitly pass the needed info into your template code.
>
> There are some exceptions to this, where the variable is statically defined in the same file or at pipeline compile time, but generally speaking, it’s probably better to use parameters for everything that does not involve system-defined read-only dynamic variable and custom-defined dynamic output variables.

So solution with separate variable template yaml is the best what is possible I think. Otherwise you need to pass all values via template parameters.

Comment: "IMHO if you want to use template you need to move this condition into task and just skip logic." I'm guessing you're right, although the docs really made me believe this is possible with the added benefit that the task would not even run at all or show up if the check has succeeded. Anyways i'm watching the bug report you posted.

Comment: You can still use your original approach but you need to move variable declaration to template and reuse it on job template.

Comment: @sommmen did you get a chance to check solution with variable template?

Comment: Hi, a seperate template file has the downside of having to configure a pipeline in 2 places now, but it seems to work. The other route like you mentioned is also a good alternative. I'm quite busy still unfortunately, but in due time i will decide to use either one. Still monitoring your bug report, although Microsoft does not seem eager to answer yet. Anyways, thanks a ton for sticking with on this, and i learned a lot - i've awarded the bounty to you for your efforts.

Comment: Don't lose hope. When Last time I reported a bug and I got notified that a proper team needs to take a look on that, the next message which I got was that bug was fixed and it would be rolled out in next few weeks.

Comment: sure thing, i'll wait this report out and otherwise i'm definitely going to post a bug on the documentation to make this a little clearer.